# Replicating an illustration for the crystal structure of ferrihydrite

Tags: crystal-structure, software

I came across this image of crystal structure in an article *[The Structure of Ferrihydrite, a Nanocrystalline Material](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1142525)* [1]:

[image: Crystal structure of ferrihydrite]

Does someone know the software in which it was produced? I have been looking for a way to visualize crystal structures of some minerals but I am stuck looking for a piece of software capable of doing it. I am aware of Jmol, but it does not show crystal structures too well.

#### References

1. Michel, F. M.; Ehm, L.; Antao, S. M.; Lee, P. L.; Chupas, P. J.; Liu, G.; Strongin, D. R.; Schoonen, M. A. A.; Phillips, B. L.; Parise, J. B. The Structure of Ferrihydrite, a Nanocrystalline Material. *Science* **2007**, 316 (5832), 1726–1729. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1142525.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the software used could be Diamond (http://www.crystalimpact.com/diamond/)

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour]. For remaining questions about the site, visit the [help]. It would be nice, if you could elaborate a little why the software you suggested is a good choice for OP’s problem. We generally prefer elaborate answers where possible. Other than that, I hope you enjoy your stay =)

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your comment. I was just answering OP's question about the software used to produce that image, so I thought no more details were needed

Comment: Which is why I didn’t downvote (it looks like it’s good) but merely mentioned ;)

Answer (score 1):

Free (as in beer) alternative to Diamond, [Olex2](http://www.olexsys.org/) (works on Windows, Linux and MacOS), can also be used to replicate this structure (I used [COD-9011573 CIF](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9011573.html)). Various bonds for cubane $\ce{Fe4O4}$ core, transparent polyhedra and custom coloring schemes are available out of the box:

[image]

There is also an extension [DrawPlus](http://www.olexsys.org/Olex2/Extensions/DrawPlus) available on a subscription basis which adds some bells and whistles alongside with extra convenient tools for visualization (though I never used it myself).