# Image of crystal structure

Tags: crystal-structure, reference-request

Is there any websites or resources where I can get a good image of a certain crystal structure? In my case I'm looking for lead(II) tungstate $\ce{PbWO4}$ and I can't find a vivid graphic on google (except of the structural formula).

I've seen [modeling structure of crystals](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40637/modeling-structure-of-crystals), but unfortunately the software is commercial.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to fetch the crystal structures of inorganic compounds via specific Google search pattern `site:crystallography.net <keyword(s)>`, e.g. in your case

`site:crystallography.net PbWO4`

yields in [this COD page](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9015950.html) where you can use JSmol to do basic visualization right in your web browser. Alternatively, you can [download CIF](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9015950.cif) and work further offline with numerous free tools such as [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/) or [Olex2](http://www.olexsys.org/). Both are free and available for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

#### Mercury

[image]

#### Olex2

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The image provided there doesn't look that good. The aim is to have a high quality image for my thesis. Is there something that matches my interests?

Comment: @Ben The image you are referring to is the one generated by JSmol script, which is very configurable in terms of visualization. Do read the [JSmol manual](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/JSmol) if you want to know more. Same for the desktop apps, there is no easy way around.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the other two tools provide nice graphics. Will have a look on them! Thank you!

Comment: @Ben No prob, but as I said, you got to read the manuals first, and it's going to take some time (an evening, maybe a couple). The "beauty" of JSmol is that you can easily see right in you browser whether that's the structure you want or not without tedious downloading and opening CIF files on the computer:)

Comment: Thanks, can you maybe recommend a certain drawing style ? My thesis is about particle physics and I only want to "show" the material we're using to detect particles. This means it's indeed more about (simple) visualization and less about specific information.

Comment: @Ben That's a broad one and there is no good answer. I'd recommend to check out recent related publications in your field and stick to what others did to show their structures. IMO in inorganic chemistry it makes sense to show the filled unit cell and draw coordination polyhedra for the atoms of interest  if you wish (Mercury cannot do that BTW, Olex2 can), and then show few projections. Images must be simple, clear and support your thesis; they are not there to be pretty, they are to be informative in the first place.

Comment: The tools seem to need too much effort for my actual purposes. But for instance, Diamond creates a nice image directly.
Sure information is more important than the graphic itself but we're no chemists (or something similar).

Comment: @Ben Diamond needs a lot tweaking as well, there is no program which would give you exactly what you want because there is no telepathic interface yet. Yes, Diamond is somewhat easier, but it's probably the only advantage; it only runs on Windows, stores structures in own proprietary format (`diamdoc`), crashes a lot, and costs a lot of money.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I got a perfect image right after importing, then I clicked somewhere and now I cannot use it anymore..  but Vesta seems to match my interests. Mercury and oxys are probably also fine but I only want an image and two weeks effort for that is not worth it (for my purposes).

Answer (score 6):

I follow a similar methods as mentioned above. First, locate the CIF file as described above.

I use [VESTA](http://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) which is a free, multiplatform molecular visualization program. Its relatively easy to get a decent image out of it (File>Export Raster Image):

[image]

You can even render vector images! You have relatively little control over the style of the image, but it works well for basic images. I usually only find myself tweaking the shininess of the atoms and bonds(Objects>properties>Atoms).

Comment: Oh, I actually forgot about this gem, very nice answer! Probably you might want to add that VESTA is also free (as a beer) and is cross-platform:)